# Golang test stdout

Tags: testing, go, ansi-escape

I am trying to test some functions that print ANSI escape codes. e.g.

```
// Print a line in a color
func PrintlnColor(color string, a ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Print("\x1b[31m")
    fmt.Print(a...)
    fmt.Println("\x1b[0m")
}
```

I tried using [Examples](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Examples) to do it, but they don't seem to like escape codes.

Is there any way to test what is written to stdout?

Comment: What's the purpose for testing stdout? It's much easier, to verify that your function produces the output you want before it's written to stdout.

Comment: The problem is stdout is the only output. The function is going to return `n int, err error` just like `fmt.Println`

Comment: you could replace `os.Stdout` with something akin to a `io.MultiWriter` that returned an `*os.File`, but it's easier to just refactor your code to make it testable. You don't need to test `fmt.Println` and `os.Stdout`, they have their own unit tests.

Comment: Yeah, write an `FprintlnColor` and then make `PrintlnColor` call it with `Stdout`. It can write to a `bytes.Buffer` for tests.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `fmt.Fprint` to print to `io.Writer` lets you control where the output is written.

```
var out io.Writer = os.Stdout

func main() {
    // write to Stdout
    PrintlnColor("foo")

    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    out = buf

    // write  to buffer
    PrintlnColor("foo")

    fmt.Println(buf.String())
}

// Print a line in a color
func PrintlnColor(a ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Fprint(out, "\x1b[31m")
    fmt.Fprint(out, a...)
    fmt.Fprintln(out, "\x1b[0m")
}
```

Go [play](http://play.golang.org/p/NHp-4i9uaE)